# jquery onclick by class

Tags: jquery, click

I would like to create a click event on all input buttons that have the class "add-another". When the buttons are clicked, I want them to reveal next TWO divs with the class "hiddenDV". My event only works for the first element. I have also tried using the on() method and had no luck with this either.

```js
$(".hiddenDV").hide();
$(".add-another").click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.hiddenDV:lt(2)').show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="button" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />

  <div class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="-" />
  </div>
  <div class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="-" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you actually hide the `.hiddenDV` elements in CSS, then your code it working absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/88645xca/

Comment: in the example mark up the second `+` is inside the div meaning it is not sibling anymore this code works if the button and the hidden div are siblings

Comment: Your code works fine for me (if you start the hidden divs as display:none)

Comment: I have ammeneded my code to make it abit more accurate what I am trying to achieve. As you can see when you run it, it reveals the first two divs but when trying to click the second + button it doesnt reveal the third/fourth divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code now look at snippet its working now..!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.hiddenDV').hide();
 $(".add-another").click(function() { $(this).parents('.row').nextAll('.hiddenDV:lt(2)').show().next('.more-buttons').show();
});
 $(".remove-another").click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.row').hide().prev('.hiddenDV').hide();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/><br />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default remove-another" value="-" />
  </div>
  <div class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default remove-another" value="-" />
  </div>
</div>
```

As I have seen you have write in your question's description that *My event only works for the first element.*

Problem was that you was unable to find the next `.hiddenDV` at second time..! because this element was not the next element of `.add-another` button..!

So added this jQuery code..

```
$(this).parents('.row').nextAll('.hiddenDV:lt(2)').show().next('.more-buttons').show();
```

Comment: Thanks for this just what i needed! Would adding a remove function to the - buttons be simply a case of copying the above jquery but saying prevAll and hide instead of show?

Comment: OKay..! @Abyssalwolf Glad it helped...! I have also updated snippet to remove the `inputs`. Look again...!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".add-another").bind("click", function () {
                var element = $(this).parent().next('div.hiddenDV');

                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    if (element.is(':hidden')) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        element = element.next('div.hiddenDV');
                    }
                }

                element.show();
            });

            $(".remove-another").bind("click", function () {

                var element = $(this).parent().next('div.hiddenDV');

                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    if (element.is(':hidden')) {
                        element = element.next('div.hiddenDV')
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                element.hide();
                
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
            </div>
             <input type="button" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default remove-another" value="-" />
        </div>
        <div id="dv1" class="row hiddenDV">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default remove-another" value="-" />
        </div>
        <div  id="dv2" class="row hiddenDV">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default remove-another" value="-" />
        </div>
```